# Combining two arrays in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Hello everybody i got a question regarding arrays in javascript, so lets get started, my question is "Can i use an array let's say it's called 'food' and it has all kinda types of food(burgers,pizza,fish), so when i get result via random function that my other function can use that result let's say it's "pizza" to get my other array that has "name, adress for places where you can eat pizza")

So it's two buttons, one input type="text" for results of first random function and span for  items for the second one that will have adresses and names of places, javascript/jquery, i can provide you with basic code which i tried

So my first thought here is to get something like switch with bunch of cases so if result of random function is "pizza" that it goes into switch - case for pizza and there it would be all info

```
"https://codepen.io/nikolamilovac/pen/yPWaxz"
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/ works for arrays, while https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ works on objects.

Comment: Why not a key => value object? `{ 'pizza' : { 'locations' : ['foo', 'bar', 'fuu'] } }`?

Comment: When you google the title of this question, the first two results in google are the jQuery methods you need...

Comment: Make an example is good for you when asking questions

Comment: "i can provide you with basic code which i tried " And you should. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://codepen.io/nikolamilovac/pen/yPWaxz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an improved version of my previous deleted answer. You don't need 2 arrays, you just need to store the value returned from the random function in order to use it when needed.

```js
var placesWhereYouCanEat = [{
  what: 'gencive de porc',
  locations: ['Paris']
}, {
  what: 'fish',
  locations: ['London']
}, {
  what: 'burger',
  locations: ['Berlin']
}],
selectedPlace;

function getRandomIndex() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * placesWhereYouCanEat.length);
}

document.getElementById('what').addEventListener('click', function () {
  selectedPlace = placesWhereYouCanEat[getRandomIndex()];
  
  document.getElementById('food').value = selectedPlace.what;
  document.getElementById('locations').innerHTML = '';
});

document.getElementById('where').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var locationsElement = document.getElementById('locations');
  locationsElement.innerHTML = '';
  
  selectedPlace.locations.forEach(function (location) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = location;
    locationsElement.appendChild(li);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="what">What do I eat ?</button>
<input id="food" type="text" />
<button id="where">Where do I eat ?</button>
<ul id="locations">
</ul>
```